# RewriteRule Needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i recently built my own web page. Now i want to use RewriteRules to be able to e.g. call "www.exampleurl.de/events" and let the server display "www.exampleurl.de/page/index.php?task=events". In the future there will be alot more pages, so a dynamic rule is needed.

The server structure looks like this:

- css

  - core.css
- image

  - header.png
  - navbar.jpg
- page

  - events.php
  - home.php
  - index.php
- .htaccess

My .htaccess file looks like this by now:

```
<IfModule mo_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/index.php?task=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope you can help me! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page/index.php?task=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```